High Resource Consumption When Sharing MS Word Files on a Server
We are using MS Word to prepare some documents , save it on a server and then share it over the network to some users.  (This is shared over an in-house application which is coded in VB.NET and uses SQL Server to store and retrieve the information).
Issue: When sharing an MS Word document on the server without setting attributes (like read-only), we notice that the application gets stuck or slows down significantly, presumably due to the load on the server when multiple users keep the document open simultaneously.
During our research, we also considered alternatives like Open Office and LibreWriter, which allow only one user to edit a document at a time, but this isn't ideal for our use case.
We have a few questions:

Why does the resource consumption increase if the attributes for the MS Word file are not set?
Is this related to the message being shown to other users when one user has the file open, leading to increased server load or cache consumption?
Is there a way to force MS Word files to open as read-only by adding command line arguments?
Alternatively, is there a method to ensure that the Word document opens in view-only mode on the client side without needing to manually set file attributes (like read-only) on the server?

Any insights, suggestions, or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!

When Word documents (or other files) are read-only, they are cached locally. The user works on a local copy of the file.
When they are not read only, the user is not working on a local copy. Sharing a network copy with other users takes more resources, and also slows everything down waiting for responses over the network.
